# Image filter kernel to expand 16-235 limited color range

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering, rgb

Is it possible to write a 5x5 kernel to process the limited color range into the full range?

This is my sample bitonal kernel, and I don't know what values to use and where to achieve this color expansion:

Grayscale

```
{ 0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.0,  0.0 }
{ 0.6,  0.6,  0.6,  0.0,  0.0 }
{ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.0,  0.0 }
{ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0 }
{ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 }
```

I would like RGB color expansion RGB 16-235 => 0-255

However i need the kernel matrix because I am not processing the image but I'm passing the matrix to a windows API function (undocumented: SetMagnificationDesktopColorEffect).

I cannot do a simple subtract/divide/multiply on the pixels. I do not have them.

Comment: I haven't got a way to test, but I think you'd put `16` or maybe `-16`, in the first 3 elements of the 4th row as an offset, and 255/(235-16) in the first 3 diagonal elements as a multiplier. http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html and https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/

Comment: 255/(235-16)  instead of the first three diagonal 1, lightens the image, however -16/16 (or anything that deviates a lot from 1.0) in the fourth row breaks the image completely, making it almost white or black.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically do it without kernel by substracting 16 from your image and then dividing it by 219. Then you will have normalized to 1 image which you have to multiply by 255 to get 255 intensity range representation.

Comment: I know that very well however the processing is not done in my application. this matrix is passed to an undocumented windows api function that applies the effect to the desktop manager. It is called SetMagnificationDesktopColorEffect in user32.dll. I need the matrix to pass to that.

Comment: Clarified in the question. Sorry.But +1 for the effort - you actually answered the question which was not well enough defined :)

Comment: This is impossible because kernel functions are spatial filtering methods, they do not deal with intensities directly but only via spatial coordinate intensities dependence on each other. It would be possible to set kernel's all entries to 0 except middle value putting there 255/235, it will increase upper bound to 255, but this is not the case for lower bound, because substraction of 16 function does not span the function of the kernel.